# Are BTStack using app approved by Apple?

Tags: iphone, ios6, bluetooth

I am at the beginning steps of using BTStack for Bluetooth connectivity based on RFCOMM protocol (between hardware approved by Apple MFi program & iPhone).

My question is that will Apple approve apps using BTStack? If not, what are the alternatives of  BTStack. The main purpose to use BTStack is to implement RFCOMM.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Does this help? http://code.google.com/p/btstack/wiki/iPhoneBluetooth

Comment: To me, it is not clear (on the link that you sent), if apple will accept or reject the app. I am hoping to hear from someone who got rejected or got approved using BTStack. Because as I am reading around, Apple might reject it and I wish to be sure to continue in this direction only if it worths. Otherwise, I'm also looking for an alternative.

Comment: t only works on jailbroken devices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BTstack-based apps require a JB device and Apple won’t approve such an app (as it won’t run on the 90+% of devices without a JB, motivates JB etc..)

BTstack cannot work inside a regular sandboxed app as it's not possible to access the Bluetooth module.

There is no way to use RFCOMM on an unmodified iOS device. The closest alternative to get RFCOMM like channel is to build your own MfI device (well, that will take time and money, and a new device) and then use the ExternalAccessory framework.

The other option could be to use Bluetooth Low Energy and either simulate serial connection over it (ugly) or use a protocol more suited for attribute/value store with your device.